# Parametrization variables $URL using JMeter

Tags: http, url, websocket, jmeter

I testing backend project in JMeter
i would like can testing both localhost and url development address.
i would like switch URL address in JMeter between localhost and url development address and can change $url variable between http://{$url} and ws://{$url}.

So I would like set variable $URL and can a change between websocket and http connection, such as I can have a choice if I would like send POST to a web socket or to a http connection.
and i would like also can a change between localhost and development URL.

What I can the best set this in JMeter ? ;) 
please describe me step by step.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to split your parameterization implementation in 2 parts:

1. Protocol (`http` or `ws`). As these 2 protocols are handled by different samplers you need to have a possibility to switch between implementations basing on some variable, the easiest way to do it is going for [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller), define your Test Plan as follows:

   - Switch Controller - Switch Value -> `${protocol}`

     - [Simple Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller) with name `http`

       - [HTTP Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
     - Simple Controller with name `ws`

       - [WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers)

         [image: JMeter Switch Controller]

So if the `${protocol}` variable value is `http` - you will have `HTTP Request` samplers executed and vice versa, check out [Selection Statements in JMeter Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/selection-statements-in-jmeter-made-easy) article for detailed explanation if needed.

2. URL variable - hopefully you know how to parameterize it, once you define its value somehow just put it into Path field of the relevant sampler

   [image: JMeter parameterize HTTP REquest]

With regards to parameterization itself, depending on where you want to have variable values there could be different approaches. Personally I stick to command-line arguments as this is the most [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)-friendly way of providing external parameters.

1. Add [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) to your Test Plan and configure it like

   [image]
2. Provide the values using [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jprotocol=http -JURL=example.com -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little inconvenient that JMeter doesn't take an [*origin*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) argument directly, but instead requires you to provide each component as a separate argument.

If you have Bash and Python at your disposal, the following one-liner will automate this process:

```
function jmorigin { python3<<<"from urllib.parse import *; a=urlsplit(\"$1\"); print('-Jserver='+a.hostname+' -Jprotocol='+a.scheme+' -Jport='+str(a.port))" ; }
```

Using this, you can simplify the parameterization of JMeter:

```
ORIGIN=https://example.com:443
jmeter $(jmorigin $ORIGIN)
```

which expands to...

```
jmeter -Jserver=example.com -Jprotocol=https -Jport=443
```